# Редактирование .class файлов

Tags: java, jar, декомпиляция

Есть JAR файл. Необходимо декомпилировать один из его классов, отредактировать одно значение и закомпилировать обратно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите сделать это одноразово, то попробуйте [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad). Но учтите, что декомпиляторы не всегда могут получить исходник из .class-файла. Предположим, вы сумели его декомпилировать верно. После этого, его надо собрать обратно. Чтобы это сделать, надо воспользоваться компилятором.

```
javac -cp исходный.jar:библиотеки.jar исправленный.класс.java
```

(если под виндой, то библиотеки надо разделять точкой с запятой вместо двоеточия)

Ну а потом запаковать с помощью утилиты jar или какого-нибудь winrar

Если JAD не выдаёт плохой исходник, то можно попробовать другие варианты декомпиляторов. В худшем случае, вам придётся после декомпиляции разбираться в байткоде и руками править неверно декомпилированный код.

**UPD**

Также есть возможность вскрыть .class-файл и править его с помощью Apache BCEL. С его помощь можно подгрузить класс, модифицировать его, а потом обратно записать. Правда Apache BCEL - программное средство, а не тула, так что вам придётся написать программу, которая бы патчила класс нужным образом.

Comment: мне нужно всего-лишь поменять стринговую строку с 12.jpg на 1.jpg Может можно сразу через байт код?

Comment: Ну тогда откройте HEX-редактором и посмотрите на нужную строчку. Жаль что надо укорачивать строку: это усложняет задачу.

Comment: А после укорачивания строки, что сделать, чтобы библиотека была рабочей?

Comment: а не проще 1.jpg переименовать в 12.jpg и заменить файлы?

Comment: А она и будет рабочей, если конечно она не подписана цифровой подписью.

Comment: У меня не вышло. После изменения в бинарном коде, начало выдавать ошибку. см http://hashcode.ru/questions/30416/  
Пытался изменить один из классов Spring3 (значение строки)  
А именно строка, которая именно эту ошибку и показывает:  
Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file org/springframework/http/converter

Comment: Ну так видимо криво исправили. Тут ведь сказано, что UTF8 строка неверна. Но вообще, если хочется быть уверенным, что сработает, то сделайте с помощью BCEL. Тогда в любом случае всё получится даже если строку надо сделать длиннее.

Comment: Когда у меня была такая необходимость (мне нужно было поменять сообщение в сторонней либе), я нашел исходник этого класса, изменил значение, и обычным javac скомпилил класс.
Затем взял архив jar, распаковал его, заменил класс, и обычным zip сжал все обратно в jar файл.